# HAProxy bind-process equivalent for threads

Tags: haproxy

HAProxy 1.8 adds an experimental [nbthread](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.1-nbthread) option which has some [benefits](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/multithreading-in-haproxy/) over nbproc. Is it possible to bind frontends to certain threads in the same way that [bind-process](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#bind-process) binds them to processes?